# What is the difference between "am Weg" and "auf dem Weg"?

Tags: preposition

I have seen both **auf dem Weg** and **am Weg** to be used in some circumstances. What is the exact difference in meaning and which one would I choose for following sentence :

> On the way to work I have stopped by
>   in the supermarket.

Comment: Short answer: You go shopping *auf dem Weg (on the way)*, but you pick flowers *am Weg (at the roadside)*. But in Austria, and only there, *am* can also mean *auf dem*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Literally *auf dem Weg* means "on the road" (on top of), *am Weg* is a contraction of *an dem Weg* and means "at the road" (near). For your example, it should be *auf dem Weg*:

> Auf dem Weg zur Arbeit habe ich kurz am Supermarkt angehalten.

If you're talking about somebody *moving*, it should always be *auf dem Weg* ("on your way"). If you're talking about something *stationary*, you should use *am Weg* ("near the road", unless it's physically *on* the road). Colloquially *auf dem Weg* is often used interchangeably with *am Weg* though.

> Auf dem Weg zur Arbeit... (that's *me moving*)
>   Der Supermarkt liegt am Weg. (that's the supermarket *standing there*)
>   Der Supermarkt liegt auf dem Weg. (auf *meinem Weg irgendwohin*)

Where you cannot simply exchange them is if you want to say something is *near the (physical) road*:

> Da steht ein Schild am Weg. (There's a sign near the road.)

Comment: Ha, I coincidentally used the sign example too! :)

Comment: Zwei Doofe, ein Gedanke. :o)

Comment: this hurts. "am" is a contraction for both "auf dem" and "an dem" and you explain the difference between those two and not between "am" and "auf dem." You can verify this by substituting "der Weg" with "die Straße" (neither "auf der" nor "an der" have a similar contraction). The contraction might be more or less in use for both "auf" and "an," depending on dialect (cf. splattne's answer).

Comment: @hop No dictionary seems to share your view of *am* as contraction of *auf dem*, and I would never use it that way. It seems to be very much a dialect use. You are correct that *an der* is not contracted to *ar*, but I'm not sure how that proves that *am* is a contraction of *auf dem*.

Comment: @hop PS: The only contraction of *auf dem* I would use is *auf'm*.

Comment: @deceze: be that as it may, you are still muddling the issue by comparing a non-contraction with a contraction and you should state that more clearly. btw, http://dwb.uni-trier.de/Projekte/WBB2009/DWB/displayLinkInfo?lemid=GA03141 is a good reference for am as a contraction for "an dem."

Comment: @hop Fair enough, added a note that *am* is a contraction. I don't think the rest of the answer should have made anybody hurt because of that somewhat tangential omission. BTW, that link doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @hop: Clearly, _am_ is a contraction of _an dem_. But I don't know how you got the idea that it's also a contraction of _auf dem_. I have no problems whatsoever with a comparison of _am_ and _auf dem_. The point is that _an dem Weg_ sounds very formal; one normally always says _am Weg_. (@deceze: Of course your recent edit is still very helpful.)

Comment: 1) if it were the clear, the original question would probably never have come up. 2) just because it is not in use in your neck of the german woods doesn't mean it's not in use anywhere. "der schlüssel liegt am kastel" as well as "ich bin am weg zu dir" is quite common in austria, colloquial or not.

Comment: @hop: Just found your comment. I didn't know about the Austrian usage (and that's not the first time this happens to me here). I found nd01's answer very helpful in this respect.

Answer (score 3):

"Am" als (zusätzliche) Kontraktion von "auf dem" ist in Österreich unauffällige Standardsprache:

- *Lebensministerium Östereich (Hrsg.)*, [Stadtundland](http://books.google.com/books?id=tq8rN5E0Wz8C&pg=PA37&dq=%22am%20Land%22&hl=de&ei=zKgVTtWDHMad-Qbhz4gW&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22am%20Land%22&f=false)
- *Mandrou, Robert*, D[ie Fugger als Grundbesitzer in Schwaben, 1560 - 1618](http://books.google.com/books?id=Kx4fmgy0CFkC&pg=PA64&dq=%22am%20Land%22&hl=de&ei=zKgVTtWDHMad-Qbhz4gW&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22am%20Land%22&f=false%20%28m%C3%B6glicherweise%20von%20einem%20%C3%96sterreicher%20%C3%BCbersetzt%29)

Ausserhalb von Österreich/Süddeutschland wird "am" meist lediglich als Kontraktion von "an dem" aufgefasst. Falls man Verwunderung oder Missverständnisse vermeiden möchte, sollte "auf dem" deshalb nicht kontrahiert werden.

Comment: I think it's worth clarifying that (1) the contraction *am* for *auf dem* is used *only* in Austria (not in southern Germany), and (2) in this context *am* is likely to be the obligatory contraction for *an dem*, after all. *Am Weg* means *at the roadside*.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you can exchange "auf dem Weg" with "am Weg" if it means "on my way to...", for example:

> Auf dem Weg in die Arbeit habe ich im Supermarkt vorbeigeschaut.
>   Am Weg in die Arbeit habe ich im Supermarkt vorbeigeschaut.

---

**EDIT:** It seems that "am Weg" is the "Austrian way" to say it (no pun intended). People from Germany seem to exclusively use *auf dem Weg*.

---

There are cases where one or the other would be more appropriate though:

> Am Weg stand ein Schild.

which means that a sign stood at the wayside.

> Auf dem Weg lag eine Bananenschale.

The banana skin was on in the middle of the path. You could use use *"am Weg"* too, but then it's not clear if it was at the edge or at your feet.

Comment: *Am Weg in die Arbeit...* - Ist das eine Mundart? Würde ich persönlich so nicht verwenden.

Comment: Just a side remark: To me, "Auf dem Weg _zur_ Arbeit" sounds more natural, but this might be a regional thing.

Comment: @deceze Jedenfalls 261k results bei Google: http://www.google.com/search?q="Am+Weg+in+die+Arbeit" - vielleicht in Österreich weiter verbreitet

Comment: I'd side with Hendrik :)

Comment: @splattne: Es sind _ungefähr_ 715.000 Ergebnisse. Wenn Du bis auf Seite 25 gehst, sind es plötzlich nur noch ungefähr 242 Ergebnisse (ohne übersprungene Ergebnisse). Bei ["Auf dem Weg zur Arbeit"](http://www.google.com/search?q="Auf+dem+Weg+zur+Arbeit") sind es am Anfang ungefähr 25.500.000 Ergebnisse, aber anzeigen will er auch nicht mehr als 610; ich weiß nicht genau, warum.

Comment: Arbeit ist eh so ein Streitwort... "Ich bin auf Arbeit" (so kenne ich es von daheim) vs. "Ich bin in der Arbeit" (so höre ich es hier in München).

Comment: +1 for the Austrian way.

Comment: *Am* for *an dem* is in fact exclusively Austrian and practically unknown in Germany. As a southern German it took me several years of living in Vienna until I understood that this is a systematic difference with an additional meaning for *am* rather than a surprisingly large number of people weirdly overusing *am = an dem*.

Answer (score 1):

You can say:

> Auf dem Weg besuchen wir noch schnell
>   einen Freund.

But you can't use 'am Weg' here because 'auf dem Weg' gets a connoation of 'unterwegs', which 'am Weg' doesn't seem to have.